# Unable to loop through nested JSON array ( uppercase properties ) with Handlebars JS with Ember JS

Tags: json, ember.js, nested, handlebars.js

I am learning Ember JS and Handlebars JS so I am very new to this.

I am having an issue trying to loop through nested JSON array's.  I am unable to loop through the 'Pages" in the JSON below.

Here is the JSON:

```
{
    "Pages": [
      {
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "Page 1",
        "Objects": [
          {
            "Width": 100,
            "Height": 200,
            "Type": "Shape"
          },
          {
            "Width": 150,
            "Height": 250,
            "Type": "Image"     
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Id": 2,
        "Name": "Page 2",
        "Objects": [

        ]
      }
    ],
    "Settings": {
        "URL": "http://THEURL",
        "Location": true,
        "Navigation": true
     },
     "Id": 1,
     "Title": "The Title",
     "Description": "The Description"
}
```

This is my handlebars template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="pages">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>{{Title}}</h1> <!-- This works -->
        <h2>{{Description}}</h2> <!-- This works -->

        <!-- This doesn't work: -->
        <ul>
        {{#each Pages}}
              <li>Page ID: {{Id}} <br /> Page Name: {{Name}} <br />
                  <ul>
                  {{#each Objects}}
                    <li>{{Type}}</li>
                  {{/each}}
                  </ul>
              </li>
        {{/each}}
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
</script>
```

Also, when I just add:

```
{{Pages}}
```

in the handlebars template, the output in the browser is:

```
[object Object],[object Object]
```

I am not sure if that is the issue or not.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear.  I can't loop through the 'Pages' nor the 'Objects' inside of the 'Pages'.  It's just blank in the browser.

Comment: If i try your code at http://tryhandlebarsjs.com it works as expected. Do you get any error messages in the js console? http://s14.directupload.net/images/140116/gup3egpg.png

Comment: Wow it works there!  This is strange it. It does not work in my Ember JS app.

Does Ember JS treat it differently?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uppercase variables are considered global scope, you need to fully qualify them or make them lowercase

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/UhIGevUf/1/edit

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>{{model.Title}}</h1> <!-- This works -->
        <h2>{{model.Description}}</h2> <!-- This works -->

        <!-- This doesn't work: -->
        <ul>
        {{#each page in model.Pages}}
              <li>Page ID: {{page.Id}} <br /> Page Name: {{page.Name}} <br />
                  <ul>
                  {{#each obj in page.Objects}}
                    <li>{{obj.Type}}</li>
                  {{/each}}
                  </ul>
              </li>
        {{/each}}
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!  This worked!  Looks like I need to fix my JSON to format it properly.