# Unable to pass dynamic data to component in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I have handlebar where I'm displaying some data and I want to use some styling so need to pass the data to a component which will process the data and display the data in the correct format. The problem is if I am passing the dynamic values from the handlebar to the component the value is not getting displayed only the hardcoded values are displyed in the component. Any reason why this is happening?

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="class">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">{{Name}}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            {{Body}} // This value is getting displayed
            {{ace-editor content=Body title=Name someText="Hello"}}
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/ace-editor">
  <pre id='editor'>{{content}} {{title}} {{someText}}</pre> // In the component only the someText values is getting displayed.
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uppercase properties are discouraged in handlebars, they usually denote a global namespace ([Unable to loop through nested JSON array ( uppercase properties ) with Handlebars JS with Ember JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164870/unable-to-loop-through-nested-json-array-uppercase-properties-with-handlebar)) and are sporadically resolved as such.  If you fully qualify your property you should be able to avoid the problem.

```
{{ace-editor content=controller.Body title=controller.Name someText="Hello"}}
```

Example:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/satiriro/2/edit

Comment: Thanks that worked! But I want to know as to why it worked in the handlebar? It shouldn't have worked there either, correct?

Comment: it's sporadic, certain parts of the code ignore it, and certain parts enforce it.  Mainly the parts that enforce it are the handlebars specific portions (since it's reminiscent of the handlebarsjs original implementation).  Honestly we should probably submit a bug, or documentation update stating this oddity.