# Cannot read property of undefined when switching from a route with a model to one without

Tags: ember.js

In the plnk below I've set up an example of the problem I'm running into. I'm new to Ember JS so I'm not certain how the system is designed to destroy models.

One route (Dashboard) has a model that consists of an array of objects. Within each object is  an "Address" property which contains an Address object. The structure is similar to the one below:

```
[{Address:{Street:'123'}}]
```

When the route is displayed it works fine, however once it's displayed and another route is activated, such as the "Logout" route, it produces an error in the console referring to the Address property. Please let me know what I might be doing wrong.

http://plnkr.co/edit/5nbJ6h0m3RCKnv6geKfi?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handlebars/Ember hates Uppercase property names, it gets confused and thinks your trying to tell it to go to the global namespace.

[Unable to loop through nested JSON array ( uppercase properties ) with Handlebars JS with Ember JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164870/unable-to-loop-through-nested-json-array-uppercase-properties-with-handlebar/21165827#21165827)

```
return [
    {
        'fileNumber': '2014-08-27-1',
        'address': {
            'street': '12345',
            'city': 'Tacoma', 
            'state': 'MA',
            'zip': '99999'
        },
        'closingDate': '02-05-2015',
        'buyerShortName': '',
        'sellerShortName': '',
        'status': 'Open'
    },
    {
        'fileNumber': '2014-09-02-1',
        'address': {
            'street': '12345',
            'city': 'Tacoma', 
            'state': 'MA',
            'zip': '99999'
        },
        'closingDate': '03-25-2015',
        'buyerShortName': '',
        'sellerShortName': '',
        'status': 'Open'
    }
];
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/XKD22mwGrkaXJUrDOcjk?p=preview

Additionally you can wrap your address section in a with, which will also fix your issue.

```
{{#with addy as item.Address}}
  <div class="tt sans13regular">
    <span class="line1">{{addy.Street}}, {{addy.City}}, {{addy.State}} {{addy.Zip}}</span>
  </div>
{{/with}}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/vbau26jUxOjavJhQmKlY?p=preview

Comment: Thanks. The #with option will be helpful for this. I've submitted an issue with Ember to see if the developers can fix this, because I believe it to be a bug. https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/5570