# Can't access dynamic property Handlebars

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have a list of elements.
For example

```
var list = [{ 'FullName': 'full name 1', 'IsCompleted': false }, 
            { 'FullName': 'full name 2', 'IsCompleted': false }]
$('#data-containter').html(template({ 'list': list }));
```

I show items of this list using HandlebarsJS by iterating it.

```
{{#each list}} // I have been trying to use {{#each element in list}}
{{#unless IsCompleted}} // And then element.IsCompleted
<tr>
  <td>{{FullName}}</td>
  <td>{{IsCompleted}}</td>
</tr>
{{/unless}}
{{/each}}
```

And everything is fine, but when I modify any element of my list by setting IsCompleted to true - still both elements show up. `list[0].IsCompleted = true`
It is like in HTML binded data is no `IsCompleted` - as the second `td` is empty.
I have read that sometimes Uppercased properties loses context, but I have changed it to lowercase and even changed whole property name.
I'd like to mention that I have many properties starting with Uppercase and this is the first problem occured.

Comment: have you tried `this.IsCompleted` ?

Comment: still nothing @TomaszBubała

Comment: you mind making an example on https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hd0rsn8g/ however, this works fine in my project it is like 'c' is always false, either if I set it to true

Comment: I can't help you, but maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164870/unable-to-loop-through-nested-json-array-uppercase-properties-with-handlebar) will.

Comment: I've seen this, but unfortunately - it didn't help